# Git - accidentally inited a repo in a repo, now can't commit

Tags: git

I have a rails app, where the the repository was inited in folder

> appname

and then another one was accidentally made in

> appname/app

Now I can't `git add` anything from app. It says directory belongs to submodule 'app'. What do I do?

Comment: Do you want to preserve any commits to `appname/app`? Otherwise you can get `rm -rf appname/app/.git`.

Comment: "It says directory belongs to submodule 'app'" - is it a submodule - or _just_ a git repository - what is the exact error message?

Comment: @AD7six, `fatal: Path 'app/controllers/' is in submodule 'app'`

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the .git folder in appname/app. Please backup the .git folder first in case you remove the wrong one by mistake.

Comment: Could also simply move/rename it

Comment: I did `rm -rf appname/app/.git` and it didn't help. There is no .git, but it still says that everything inside /app belongs to submodule 'app'

Answer (score 0):

If it is a submodule

```
git submodule deinit
```

is the way to go. See [ths answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule).

Comment: What dir do I iput the command from? Do I need to put the name of the submodule somewhere?

Comment: What is exact output of command `git submodule summary` from your appname dir?

Comment: `fatal: Path 'app/controllers/' is in submodule 'app' `

Comment: run `git submodule deinit app` from appname.

Comment: `No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'app'` what the hell?

Comment: hmm... `cat .gitmodules`. Also is there a .git folder in 'app/controllers/' path? Remove it in that case.